# ¿Cómo uso el resultado de un cálculo en la siguiente iteración de un bucle?

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo una operación matemática y quiero que se guarde en una variable final que le puse  "fy"

Pero necesito que ese resultado ahora se guarde en una nueva variable y continúe haciendo esa misma operación hasta que llegue a un límite.

**Código**:

```
import math

print("Operación Matemática")

x= float(input("Ingresa el valor de x "))
y= float(input("Ingresa el valor de y "))
h= float(input("Ingresa el valor de h"))
xfin=int(input("Determina el valor final de x"))

for i in range(xfin):
    fy= ((y+(0.1))*(0.1)*(math.sqrt(y))+(0.4))*math.pow(x,2)  

print("resultado es ", fy)
```

Lo que quiero es que, se guarde el valor de fy y se reemplace ahora por "y" y que se haga otra vez esa operación pero con el nuevo valor de y digamos

```
4.5
4.20
4.60
```

Etc, etc, la verdad no se cómo hacerlo espero su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

simplemente reasigna la variable `y`.

Sólo tienes que cambiar todas las `fy` por `y`

```
print("Operación Matemática")
x= float(input("Ingresa el valor de x "))
y= float(input("Ingresa el valor de y "))
h= float(input("Ingresa el valor de h"))
xfin=int(input("Determina el valor final de x"))

for i in range(xfin):
    y = ((y+(0.1))*(0.1)*(math.sqrt(y))+(0.4))*math.pow(x,2)

print("resultado es ", y)
```

Comment: Perfecto, pero ahora, me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que el X cambie también, o sea, pueda pasar digamos 2 a 2.1, 2.2 y así cambiar en la operación

Comment: Pero, te lo acaba de decir amigo. Al reasignar la variable, estas iterando sobre la misma. Es decir, le vas agregando el valor. Ahora, lo que puede que suceda, es que en realidad lo que te confunde es la operacion matematica en si, y no la iteracion del codigo.

Comment: @JoseRocket. Tienes que escribir algo del estilo `x = expresion_que_calcula_nuevo_valor_de_x`